# TensorFlow: argmax (-min)

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, tensorflow

I just noticed an unexpected (at least for me) behavior in TensorFlow. I thought `tf.argmax` (-`argmin`) operates on the ranks of a Tensor from outer to inner, but apparently it does not?!

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

arr = np.array([[31, 23,  4, 24, 27, 34],
                [18,  3, 25,  0,  6, 35],
                [28, 14, 33, 22, 20,  8],
                [13, 30, 21, 19,  7,  9],
                [16,  1, 26, 32,  2, 29],
                [17, 12,  5, 11, 10, 15]])

# arr has rank 2 and shape (6, 6)
tf.rank(arr).eval()
> 2
tf.shape(arr).eval()
> array([6, 6], dtype=int32)
```

`tf.argmax` takes two arguments: `input` and `dimension`. Since the indices of array `arr` are `arr[rows, columns]`, I would expect `tf.argmax(arr, 0)` to return the index of the maximum element per row, while I would have expected `tf.argmax(arr, 1)` to return the maximum element per column. Likewise for `tf.argmin`.

However, the opposite is true:

```
tf.argmax(arr, 0).eval()
> array([0, 3, 2, 4, 0, 1])

# 0 -> 31 (arr[0, 0])
# 3 -> 30 (arr[3, 1])
# 2 -> 33 (arr[2, 2])
# ...
# thus, this is clearly searching for the maximum element
# for every column, and *not* for every row

tf.argmax(arr, 1).eval()
> array([5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 0])

# 5 -> 34 (arr[0, 5])
# 5 -> 35 (arr[1, 5])
# 2 -> 33 (arr[2, 2])
# ...
# this clearly returns the maximum element per row,
# albeit 'dimension' was set to 1
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

Generalized every n-dimensional Tensor `t` is indexed by `t[i, j, k, ...]`. Thus, `t` has rank n and shape `(i, j, k, ...)`. Since dimension 0 corresponds to `i`, dimension 1 to `j`, and so forth. Why does `tf.argmax` (& -`argmin`) ignore this scheme?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Think of the `dimension` argument of `tf.argmax` as the axis across which you reduce. `tf.argmax(arr, 0)` reduces across dimension `0`, i.e. the rows. Reducing across rows means that you will get the argmax of each individual column.

This might be counterintuitive, but it falls in line with the conventions used in `tf.reduce_max` and so on.

Comment: Also same conventions as numpy's [`argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)

Comment: Can you explain why reducing across rows implicates getting the argmax of each individual column? Additionally: how does this behave for n-dimensional Tensors? I'm a bit lost at figuring out which dimension relates to reducing `i, j, k, l` or `m` in a 5D-Tensor.

Comment: By definition, if you search for the maximum _across_ rows, you are searching _within_ columns.

For any ``d``-dimensional array, taking the ``argmax`` _across_ the ``i``th axis means that, for any possible combination of the ``d-1`` remaining indices, you are searching for the maximum _amongst_ ``arr[ind1, ind2, ..., ind_i_minus_1, : , ind_i_plus_1, ..., ind_d]``.

Answer (score 1):

In an n-dimensional Tensor, any given dimension has n-1 dimensions that form a discrete 2 dimensional subspace. Following the same logic, it has n-2 3 dimensional subspaces, all the way down to n - (n-1), n dimensional subspaces. You could express any aggregation as a function within the remaining subspace(s), or across the subspace(s) that are being aggregated. Since the subspace will no longer exist after the aggregation, Tensorflow has chosen to implement it as an operation across that dimension.

Frankly, it's an implementation choice by the creators of Tensorflow, now you know.